# CSS Padding Right

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to figure out, how to disable the padding-right on only one of the navigation links.

```
#nav ul li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

That code puts 15px of padding on the right of the navigation text, however the very last navigation link, I want to have no padding, because it is uneven with my centered text.

I have tried something like this:

```
.nopad {
padding: 0;
}
```

Then adding this to my links:

```
<li class="nopad"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to padding: `#nav ul li.nopad { padding: 0!important; }`

 This will override any inherited CSS padding

Else you could just change `padding:0;` to `padding:0 !important;`

Comment: You can learn more about !important here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
#nav ul li.nopad { padding: 0; }
```

Other property is overriding it.

If you want to know more about CSS specificity read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: You might want to explain why it's being overridden.

Comment: Its being overwritten because your class is applied to the li item. As the li ul item is more specific it, classes defined specifically for it will take precedence